# PHP string comparison with no quotes

Tags: php, string

From what I know about PHP, the following syntax is **not** legal:

```
if ($s == Yes)
```

It should instead be written as:

```
if ($s == 'Yes')
```

However, the first example is working just fine. Anyone know why?

Comment: Always develop PHP with ALL error reporting on. All the invisible notices do slow down your application, and make it unusable to others who haven't disabled error reporting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ordinarily, it would be interpreted as a constant, but if PHP can't find a constant by that name, then it assumes it to be a string literal despite the lack of quotes. This will generate an E_NOTICE message (which may not be visible, depending on your error reporting level); something like:

> Notice:  Use of undefined constant Yes - assumed 'Yes' in script.php on line 3

Basically, PHP is just overly lenient.

Answer (score 8):

In short, PHP is acting as if the quotes were there.

If PHP doesn't recognize something as a reserved token, it treats it as a string literal.

The error log will show a warning about this.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not a string.

And it is not works fine:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if ($s == Yes) {}
```

It's a legacy from the times when PHP were just a "Pretty home page" form interpreter and strongly discouraged nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both error_reporting showing notices, and display_errors set on.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if ($s == Yes) {
  // foo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP that Yes would be treated as a constant. If the constant is undefined it will assume you meant the string 'Yes'. It should generate a notification if you have them turned on.

Answer (score 0):

PHP converts Yes to 'Yes' internally when constant Yes is found not to be defined.

Btw.. If what you want is comparing if $s has "Yes" as value an is a string  then you have to

a) use strcmp or 
b) use the identity operator "==="